# Recursion return a list with 2 elements in python

Tags: python, recursion

i want the function to store a list or a tuple with two strings in it. The diffrent strings is dependent  on wether the character is lower or upper case, if not in the alphabet it should be removed. The functions should be strictly recursive and no extra parameters to the function. how do i get this done?

```
def recursive(message):
        if message > 0:

               if message[0].islower():

                    return message[0] + recursive(message[1:]), 


               if message[0].isupper():
                    return message[0] + recursive(message[1:]),

               else:
                    return recursive(message[1:])



first, second = recursive("HalleLUJAh")

first should then hold ("alleh")
second should then hold ("HLUJA")
```

Comment: What should the output be ? `first` -> `alleh` and `second` -> `HLUJA` ?

Comment: yes exactly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def split_case(sentence)
    lower, upper  = "", ""
        for char in sentence:
            if char.islower():
                lower += char
            else:
                upper += char
    return lower, upper
```

Comment: forgot to mention that it must be strictly recursive, meaning no iterations

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursive_split(message):
    if message:
        first, second = recursive_split(message[1:])
        if message[0].isupper():
            return first, message[0] + second
        else:
            return message[0] + first, second

    else:
        return "", ""

print(recursive_split("HalleLUJAh")) # ('alleh', 'HLUJA')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use something like,

```
$ cat rec.py
def recursive(word):
    lower, upper = "", ""
    if word:
        if word[0].islower():
            lower += word[0]
            f, s = recursive(word[1:])
            lower += f
            upper += s
        else:
            upper += word[0]
            f, s = recursive(word[1:])
            lower += f
            upper += s
    return lower, upper

first, second = recursive("HalleLUJAh")
print(first, second)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python rec.py
('alleh', 'HLUJA')
```